# How to deserialise json into Java object with nested generics

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, gson

I'm trying to deserialise using Gson (though happy to try Jackson if that can do it) the following json into the following nested object.

```
[
 {
   "ID": 1,
   "title": "title1",
   "numbers": [1,2]
 },
 {
   "ID": 2,
   "title": "title2",
   "numbers": [10,20]
 }
]
```

into a `List<MyObject>`

with the following POJOs

**MyObject**

```
public class MyObject {

    private BaseModel<Integer> id;
    private BaseModel<String> title;
    private BaseListModel<Integer> numbers;

}
```

**BaseModel**

```
public class BaseModel<T> {

    protected T value;

    public BaseModel() {
    }

    public BaseModel(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value){
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**BaseListModel**

```
public class BaseListModel<T> extends BaseModel<List<T>> {

    public BaseListModel() {
        value = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void addValue(T value) {
        this.value.add(value);
    }

    public void removeValue(T value) {
        this.value.remove(value);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm getting at the moment, is my json for id or title is a value not an object which is what gson is expecting to find, because of the `BaseModel<Integer>` or `BaseModel<String>`. Is it possible to add some config to the gson using maybe `GsonBuilder` or writing my own deserializer?

Answer (score 0):

For GSON you might need to do some deserializer logic which might be nasty job.

For Jackson it might be a lot easier. You could use `@JsonCreator`. First, to make Jackson happy, add this to your `BaseModel`:

```
@JsonProperty("ID") // or change the JSON to have lower ID
private BaseModel<Integer> id;
```

Then tell what constructors to use like adding this to your `BaseModel`:

```
@JsonCreator
public BaseModel(T value) {
```

and for your `BaseListModel` add a new constructor, like:

```
@JsonCreator
public BaseListModel(List<T> list) {
    value = list;
}
```

Comment: Becuase I was short on time, I just made a middle POJO that matched the fields in the JSON, and then a small converted class that used the values of that "middle step POJO" to create my final class. I will look into using Jackson though when I do more of this as I'm at proof of concept stage at the moment. Thanks